# Express the Gaussian curvature of $f(S)$ in terms of the Gaussian curvature of $S$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x)=cx$ for some constant $c\neq0$ and $S$ be a regular surface. Then how can I express the Gaussian curvature of $f(S)$ in terms of the Gaussian curvature of $S$?

Comment: is it $c^2$ times the Gaussian curvature of $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal K(u,v)$ be the gaussian curvature, it is given by

$$\mathcal K(u,v)=\frac{\det(II)}{\det(I)}$$

$\det(I)=||x_u||^2||x_v||^2 -\langle x_u,x_v\rangle ^2$

$\det(II)=\langle x_{uu}, \mathbf {\hat n}\rangle \langle x_{vv}, \mathbf{\hat n}\rangle - \langle x_{uv}, \mathbf {\hat n}\rangle ^2$

Where $\mathbf {\hat n}=\frac{x_u \times x_v}{||x_u \times x_v||}$

Now look if $f(S)=cS(u,v)$, check that

$\det(I')=c^4 \det(I)$

$ \mathbf{ \hat n'}= \mathbf{\hat n}$

$\det(II')=c^2 \det(II)$

Curvature for $f(S)$:

$$K'(u,v)=\frac 1{c^2} K(u,v)$$

This makes sense if you view the Gaussian curvature as the reciprocal of the radius of the best fit sphere, if you scale it larger, the curvature will decrease, just like curvature for sphere is proportional to $\frac 1{r^2}$

Comment: Very clear! Thanks so much

Comment: @fisher You are welcome :)